# To remove duplicate records

Tags: apex

I have a query which returns duplicate records. I need to remove all duplicates from it and store all unique records in a list.
         I'm trying to assign non duplicate records including id to tempList.
         Please suggest a method to achieve this.
Thanks.

```
    Map<String,temp_object__c> tempMap = new Map<String,temp_object__c>([select id,name,string,string1,string2 from temp_object__c]);
         List<temp_object__c> tempList = new List<temp_object__c>();
         for(String key: tempMap.keyset()){
         //here i need to assign to tempList
}
```

Comment: what is the criteria to check a record is duplicate

Comment: field string1 shouldn't be duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Set<String>` as set contains only unique values and add the field string1 into unique set and check in the loop if the value doesn't exists in the set then only add the value in the `tempList`

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new Set<String>();
Map<String,temp_object__c> tempMap = new Map<String,temp_object__c>([select id,name,string,string1,string2 from temp_object__c]);
List<temp_object__c> tempList = new List<temp_object__c>();
for(String key: tempMap.keyset()){
   //here i need to assign to tempList
   if(!uniqueSet.contains(tempMap.get(key).string1)){
      //FIRST ADD THE STRING TO SET AND ADD IN THE LIST
      uniqueSet.add(tempMap.get(key).string1);
      tempList.add(tempMap.get(key));
   }
}
```